# Unlock PC with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, script, scheduled-tasks, lock, automatic-logon

I need to set up a Scheduled Task to unlock Windows 7 PC at specific time. And second Task, to lock at other specific time. Is this possible by cmd.exe command, or I need to use some third party software? By unlock I meen unlock logon screen.

What I'm trying to achieve with this process:

I have PC, where is running instance of TeamViewer. TeamViewer works only when user is logged on and screen is not blocked. I want to set up at specific time PC screen unlock, so I can remote login into this PC with TeamViewer app. I don't want to setup VPN, I don't want to open ports and allow RDP or VNC, only way I want to connect to this PC is TeamViewer app. I am trying to find out how to setup PC screen unlock with Windows Task Scheduler.

**UPDATE:**

- Thanks to [*user2196728 comment*](https://superuser.com/questions/837638/unlock-pc-with-windows-task-scheduler#comment1102349_837638) I know how to lock screen(`rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` from `cmd`), but still I don't know the most important thing for me - how to unlock it in the first place.
- There is utility [Logon.exe](http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/51.htm) to unlock Windows PC, but I couldn't get it to work on Windows 7, I don't know, maybe it's not working on Windows 7.
- I understand that for unlock will be required to store user password. In this case, I suppose there is possibility to use plain text. It can look a bit terrifying, but I don't store any sensitive data on this machine. First let's see what can be done, and then, what is best secure way/options to encrypt password.

Comment: To lock you can use `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` from `cmd`. However how do you plan to manage the user password required (i hope) to unlock ?

Comment: I think we should first talk about what are you trying to achieve with this process ?

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: I updated question with more details.

Comment: I have the same requirements. I need to unlock some computers to allow them to serve as build agents for continuous integration (nightly GUI testing). Did you find a solution?

Comment: [Have a look over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830666/run-command-script-when-lock-unlock-windows-station)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Teamviewer options... `Security > Windows Login`. Mine is set for Administrators Only (I run from an administrator account), but you can also select all users.

The resultant behavior is that I can connect to my machine regardless of whether it is sitting at the initial login screen, at the desktop, or at the lock screen. I can then log in/unlock interactively just like I'm sitting at my desk.